# LINUX - Left Join 2 txt tables with headers

Tags: linux, join

Below, I have 2 tables with example data that I want to do a join. I want all data from PROJECT_NAME.txt and only data from PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt that matches.

What I first found, is that it seems I needed to sort. Once I did that, my headers became a problem. My output is still missing a couple of lines and worst of all the output table has one table one line and another table another line. It needs to be one line. How would I do this properly? Below is the data from the 2 tables, what I did, and the output.

PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt

```
PROJECT_ID  CITY    STATE   ZIP    
7   DENVER  CO  80237
5   DENVER  CO  80231
8   LAKEWOOD    CO  80123    
1   LAKEWOOD    CO  80227
4   LAKEWOOD    CO  80228
3   ENGLEWOOD   CO  80110
10  ENGLEWOOD   CO  80113    
2   ENGLEWOOD   CO  80120
9   DENVER  CO  80203    
6   DENVER  CO  80022
```

PROJECT_NAME.txt

```
PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_DUE_DATE
4   VERITAS 04/10/2022
7   GLADIUS 06/30/2022
1   SCUTUM  02/01/2022
```

These are the commands I've used:

```
max-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test$ join -1 1 -2 1 PROJECT_NAME.txt PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt >combined.txt
join: PROJECT_NAME.txt:4: is not sorted: 1  SCUTUM  02/01/2022
join: PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt:3: is not sorted: 5 DENVER  CO  80231

max-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test$ sort PROJECT_NAME.txt > project_name.txt

max-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test$ sort PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt > project_locations.txt

max-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Test$ join -1 1 -2 1 project_name.txt project_locations.txt >combined.txt
join: project_locations.txt:3: is not sorted: 1 LAKEWOOD    CO  80227
```

This is the result, combined.txt

```
4 VERITAS 04/10/2022
 LAKEWOOD CO 80228    
7 GLADIUS 06/30/2022
DENVER CO 80237
PROJECT_ID PROJECT_NAME PROJECT_DUE_DATE
 CITY STATE ZIP
```

You can see it pulls #4, #7, then the header files. for #4, LAKEWOOD is on a separate line altogether. Is there a better way to do this? Why did 1  SCUTUM  02/01/2022 completely disappear?

Here is the output I was hoping for:

```
PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_DUE_DATE    CITY    STATE   ZIP
4   VERITAS 04/10/2022  LAKEWOOD    CO  80228
7   GLADIUS 06/30/2022  DENVER  CO  80237
1   SCUTUM  02/01/2022  LAKEWOOD    CO  80227
```

When I tried When I try awk 'BEGIN{print "PROJECT_ID PROJECT_NAME PROJECT_DUE_DATE CITY STATE ZIP"} FNR==NR{if(FNR>1){a[$1]=$0}} FNR!=NR{if(FNR>1){if($1 in a){print a[$1],$2,$3,$4}}}' PROJECT_NAME.txt PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt and export it out (like) awk 'BEGIN{print "PROJECT_ID PROJECT_NAME PROJECT_DUE_DATE CITY STATE ZIP"} FNR==NR{if(FNR>1){a[$1]=$0}} FNR!=NR{if(FNR>1){if($1 in a){print a[$1],$2,$3,$4}}}' PROJECT_NAME.txt PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt > combined.txt

it is placing fields from PROJECT_NAME.txt on one line and PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt on the other like so.

PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_DUE_DATE    CITY    STATE   ZIP

7   GLADIUS 06/30/2022

DENVER CO 80237

1   SCUTUM  02/01/2022

LAKEWOOD CO 80227

4   VERITAS 04/10/2022

LAKEWOOD CO 80228

Why is it putting on 2 lines? The combined.txt is the export file I need it exported to.

Comment: You're comparing horses with lego :)  SQL is a database query language, Linux is an operating system.  For all it's worth you could import your text files into one of the many available RDBMS' and proceed as you're used to.

Comment: P.S.: Can you add the desired output to your question as well?

Comment: For me this question belongs to superuser.com

Comment: I put the output in the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not using the tool that you asked for, but this works, I think.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_DUE_DATE    CITY    STATE   ZIP"} FNR==NR{if(FNR>1){a[$1]=$0}} FNR!=NR{if(FNR>1){if($1 in a){print a[$1],$2,$3,$4}}}' PROJECT_NAME.txt PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt 
PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_DUE_DATE    CITY    STATE   ZIP
7   GLADIUS 06/30/2022 DENVER CO 80237
1   SCUTUM  02/01/2022 LAKEWOOD CO 80227
4   VERITAS 04/10/2022 LAKEWOOD CO 80228
```

Comment: When I try awk 'BEGIN{print "PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_DUE_DATE    CITY    STATE   ZIP"} FNR==NR{if(FNR>1){a[$1]=$0}} FNR!=NR{if(FNR>1){if($1 in a){print a[$1],$2,$3,$4}}}' PROJECT_NAME.txt PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt  and export it out (like) awk 'BEGIN{print "PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_DUE_DATE    CITY    STATE   ZIP"} FNR==NR{if(FNR>1){a[$1]=$0}} FNR!=NR{if(FNR>1){if($1 in a){print a[$1],$2,$3,$4}}}' PROJECT_NAME.txt PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt > combined.txt it is placing fields from PROJECT_NAME.txt on one line and PROJECT_LOCATIONS.txt on the other. Why is it putting on 2 lines?

Comment: @Martha I believe is best if you update your question with those details, to make them more readable

Comment: Hard to say ... did you create the files in windows?  Might be DOS line-endings biting you.